# finding the mean in normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am struggling on this question where I need to find the mean given the standard deviation.
The question is the following:

```
A certain brand of flood lamps has a length of life that is normally distributed, 
with a standard deviation of 392 hours.
If 8 % of the lamps last more than 5600 hours, what is the mean length of life?
```

This is what I've tried so far

let $X$ = length of light

$X\sim\mathcal{N}(\text{mean = unknown }(u), SD = 392)$

$P(X > 5600) = 0.8$

$1 - P(X < 5600) = 0.8$ (stuck after this part)

$1 - P(5600-u/392 < 5600) = 0.8$ ( incorrect)

I am having troubles working backwards to the find the mean.
Could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}[X>5600]=8\%=0.08$$

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq 5600]=92\%=0.92$$

that is

$$\Phi\Bigg[\frac{5600-\mu}{392}\Bigg]=0.92$$

Now using Z-table you get

$$\frac{5600-\mu}{392}=1.4051$$

that is

$$\mu=5049$$

---

**How to read a Z-table**

[image]

I used a calculator. With Paper -table you get that the quantile corresponding to the probability of $0.92$ is between $1.40$ and $1.41$, more or less exactly in the middle...

Comment: how are you getting 1.4051 from the Z-table?
when i look at the 0.9 row and 0.02 column i get a value of  0.8212

Comment: @william_ ; see my edits. Row+Column is the quantile. The probability is in the table body

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
X &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 392^2) \\
P(X \le 5600) &= 0.92 \\
P \left( Z \le \frac{5600 - \mu}{392} \right) &= 0.92 \tag{normalize} \\
\mu \approx 5600 - 392 (1.41) &= 5047.28 \tag{check standard normal table}
\end{align}

P.S. My answer used $\approx$ instead of $=$ as the value is only an approximation.